# solve $L=\int_0^4 \sqrt{1+\frac{9}{4}y^4+\frac{9}{2}y^2}dy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need help with this excercise.

Find the arc length of the function $$x=\frac{1}{2}(y^2+2)^{3/2}$$
from $y=0$ to $y=4$.

---

$$L=\int_a^b \sqrt{1+(\frac{dx}{dy})^2}dy$$

Now, $$x=\frac{1}{2}(y^2+2)^{3/2}$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{3}{2}y\sqrt{y^2+2}$$

Then,

$$L=\int_0^4 \sqrt{1+(\frac{3}{2}y\sqrt{y^2+2})^2}dy$$
$$L=\int_0^4 \sqrt{1+\frac{9}{4}y^4+\frac{9}{2}y^2}dy$$

How to solve this integral?

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sqrt(1%2B9%2F4*y%5E4%2B9%2F2*y%5E2)) provides a quite complicate indefinite integral. The result you want probably comes with some sort of trick, unless you are some kind of integration-super-ninja :D

Comment: and, this exercise was an exam yesterday!!

Comment: Is it in a regular calculus course, or does it involves some advanced techniques?

Comment: There's something strange about the statement. It mentions that $0\leqslant y\leqslant4$, but actually $y$ is always at least $\sqrt2$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Actually, $x\geq \sqrt{2}$. The domain of $x(y)$ is all the real numbers, and the image is $[\sqrt{2},\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

We can instead take the parametrization

$y=\sqrt{2}\tan(a), x=\sqrt{2}\sec^3({a})$

$y'^2=2\sec^4(a), x'^2=18\sec^6(a)\tan^2(a)$

We then need to compute

$\int_{0}^{\arctan(2\sqrt{2})} \sqrt{18\sec^6(a)\tan^2(a)+2\sec^4(a)}da$

Making the substiution $u=\tan{a}$ transfomrs the integral to

$\int_{0}^{2\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{18u^2+20}du$

Now take $u=\sqrt{\frac{20}{18}}\sinh{v}$

then we're done hope you can continue from here